# Re-arranging a timestamp with a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to re-arrange a timestamp with a Perl regex with the least code possible.  The original format of the time stamp is as follows:

```
2011/12/29 20:19:45
```

All I need to do is convert it so that the year at the front instead comes after the month/date as follows:

```
12/29/2011 20:19:45
```

I was able to achieve this with the 3 lines of code below.  I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this with less code.  In particular I tried to do away with the middle line saving $1 into an intermediate variable, and specifying $1 from the first substitution directly in the regex for the second substitution, but this resulted in the error: "Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string."

If the second line cannot be gotten rid of, then it would seem like this can't be gotten down to one line either?

```
#my $ts = '2011/12/29 20:19:45'; #input to a subroutine

$ts =~ s/^(\d{4})\///;
my $year = $1;
$ts =~ s/ /\/$year /;
```

Comment: +1 on George's comment.  Please don't down-mod without an explanation.  That's not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are you go:

```
$ts =~ s|^(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})(.+)$|$2/$3/$1$4|;
```

Please note that the above expression expects timestamps having *exactly* 2 digits for months and days and 4 digits for years. But you can make it even shorter yet more reliable:

```
$ts =~ s|^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(.+)$|$2/$3/$1$4|;
```

This one will handle timestamps like 1/12/98 12:34:56 properly.

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer including explanation and improvement over my "leaning toothpicks"

Comment: Any time. BTW, you can make the regex even more short by combining day and month together: `s|^(\d+)/(\d+/\d+)(.+)$|$2/$1$3|` :)

Comment: Good answer.  Both the question and answer were helpful to me, duly up-modded.

Comment: I tend not to combine day/month together, if only because there are lots of different date formats. Keeping fields grouped makes is more sensible if you ever intend to use the code in something similar again.

Comment: There is no need to capture the rest of the string. If you didn't specify it to change, it won't. Shorter yet is `s|(\d{4})/(\d+)/(\d+)|$2/$3/$1|;`

Comment: Good point: "no need to capture the rest of the string" .... I wasn't doing so in the first place.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Using Back References you can get the desired formatting -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "2011/12/29 20:19:45" | 
perl -pe 's@([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})@$3/$1/$2@'
29/2011/12 20:19:45
```

Comment: `\3` etc better written as `$3`.

Comment: True ... I don't really know `perl` just used it's `sed` capabilities. Will update the answer as it looks better and thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

For more generic timestamp manipulation you possibly want to roundtrip via `strptime`/`strftime`. In this case it's just field reordering, but for more complex cases such as turning month numbers into names, `strftime` will be required.

```
my @t = strptime "2011/12/29 20:19:45", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S";

say strftime "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", @t;    #  29/12/2011 20:19:45
say strftime "%d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S", @t;   #  29 December 2011, 20:19:45
```